# LegendLayout not working as asked

Tags: plotting, legending

Why the following code does not result in row layout as specified (see the attached picture for result)?

```
LineLegend[{Red, Blue}, {Abs[Subscript[a, 2]/Subscript[a, 1]], 
  Abs[Subscript[a, 3]/Subscript[a, 1]]}, LegendLayout -> "Row"]
```

Here is a workaround to have row legend in this case. Nevertheless let me ask because I was wondering if it is a bug or I did anything wrong with the above code.

```
LineLegend[{Red, Blue}, {Abs[Subscript[a, 2]/Subscript[a, 1]], 
  Abs[Subscript[a, 3]/Subscript[a, 1]]}, 
 LegendLayout -> (Grid[{Flatten@#}] &)]
```

The result is as follows:

[image]

Comment: @Yi You should consider to add the nice solution you found as an answer to the above link

Comment: @SimonWoods Oh, he is my collaborator and asked exactly the same question :)